# Is there JQuery Datatable "deprecation guide"

Tags: jquery, documentation, datatables

I'm new to JQuery and Datatable and I've inherited some code that uses some "legacy" methods from an earlier version such as this:

```
oList = $('#mylist').dataTable( {
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": false,
    "cache": false,
    "sAjaxSource": url,
    "sAjaxDataProp": "payload.listOfStuff",
    "aoColumns": [
                   { "mData": "Id" , "sTitle": "Audio ID", "sWidth":"10%"},  
                   { "mData": "columnB" , "sTitle": "Column B", "sWidth":"45%"},   
                   { "mData": "columnC", "sTitle": "Column C", "sWidth":"45%"},   

               ]
});
```

From the JQuery DataTable site, I learn that aoColumns is a feature from version 1.9 or before, and is not part of the recommended 1.10 toolset, though it does work.

Now I want to add some new tricks to this table such as clickable links, and all the examples I find use other methods of presenting this data associated with the current 1.10 version, and it's not clear how or if they would fit together.

My questions are these:

1. Is there a site that explains how to convert the old "legacy"
   methods to the new recommended practice?  For example, what to use
   instead of aoColumns?
2. Given that I'm using aoColumns (or any JQuery defined data element),
   where is the document that explains what goes in "mData", and what
   other elements are possible within an aoColumn?  I realize that some of then are self-explanatory,"sWidth" for example, but others aren't.  Why "mData" rather than "Data"?  Is there no recourse other than to read the javascript?

In short I'm looking for something like a javadoc, and what I'm finding are a bunch of "howto do this or that cool trick" pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search of the datatables site showed this guide:

http://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert

and the legacy docs:

http://legacy.datatables.net/

Comment: Thank you, this is at least most of what I was looking for.